# Assign Cycle number basis the date column in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

my current dataframe includes date column. i want to add an another column named as "Cycle Number".

i want cycle number to be created using below rule :

cycle 1 : if date inbetween 4th Jan to 3rd Feb (including both the dates i.e. start & end date)

cycle 2 : if date inbetween 4th Feb to 3rd March and so on till

cycle 12 : if date inbetween 4th Dec to 3rd Jan

i have data from 2018. cycle number should reset to 1 with start of new year

current approach doesn't work well

```
# code that i have tried 

def assign_transaction_cycle(date):
    year = date.year
    month = date.month
    day = date.day

    # Calculate the cycle number
    if (month == 1 and day >= 4) or (month == 12 and day <= 3):
        return f'cycle-1'
    elif (month == 2 and day >= 4) or (month == 1 and day <= 3):
        return f'cycle-2'
    elif (month == 3 and day >= 4) or (month == 2 and day <= 3):
        return f'cycle-3'
    elif (month == 4 and day >= 4) or (month == 3 and day <= 3):
        return f'cycle-4'
    elif (month == 5 and day >= 4) or (month == 4 and day <= 3):
        return f'cycle-5'
    elif (month == 6 and day >= 4) or (month == 5 and day <= 3):
        return f'cycle-6'
    elif (month == 7 and day >= 4) or (month == 6 and day <= 3):
        return f'cycle-7'
    elif (month == 8 and day >= 4) or (month == 7 and day <= 3):
        return f'cycle-8'
    elif (month == 9 and day >= 4) or (month == 8 and day <= 3):
        return f'cycle-9'
    elif (month == 10 and day >= 4) or (month == 9 and day <= 3):
        return f'cycle-10'
    elif (month == 11 and day >= 4) or (month == 10 and day <= 3):
        return f'cycle-11'
    else:
        return f'cycle-12'  

---------------------------------------------------------------
# Input Data

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['26-01-2021', '27-02-2021',...,'06-01-2022']})

---------------------------------------------------------------

Expected Output :

Date            Cycle Number
26-01-2021            1
27-02-2021            2
.
.
.
22-12-2021            12
06-01-2022             1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subtract 3 days from the original date then extract the month:

The cycle of '2021-01-02' should be 12 so '2021-01-02 - 3 days' is '2020-12-30'.

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
offset = pd.DateOffset(days=3)
df['cycle'] = dates.sub(offset).dt.month
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         Date  cycle
0  26-01-2021      1
1  27-02-2021      2
2  06-01-2022      1
```